# Why I get hibernate.cfg.xml not found even if my xml file is in src/main/resources in maven project?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

I am building an maven-based app where I want to use Hibernate for work with DB. I read a lot of articles where writes that, when I have Maven project, I must put my xml file into src/main/resources. And I have done that but I am again getting error. This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">""</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <mapping class="pojo.Student"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I added this file into JavaResources/src/main/resources.

This is my FirstDemo class:

```
public class DemoFirst {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName("Bob");
        student.setAge(26);

        session.save(student);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();

    }
```

And this is error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pack.DemoFirst.main(DemoFirst.java:12)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
    at pack.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: is this when you run the code from within an IDE? If it is, which IDE?

Comment: This is when I run app in eclipse...

Comment: is the src/main/resources directory declared as a source directory in your build path?

Comment: How to see that? Path to the my file is JavaResources/src/main/resources

Comment: I don't have Eclipse in front of me, but I think you right click on a file in the package explorer and choose "Configure Build Path". Once you've done that, there is a source tab that allows you to say which directories are source directories AFAIR

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Maven, but "normally" your hibernate.cfg.xml should be named precisely like that and goes directly in your classes-folder (the "Output directory", as it is named in Eclipse)

I hope that helps?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Student student = new Student();
student.setFirstName("Bob");
student.setAge(26);

session.save(student);
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();
```

could you please try this. it may help you.

Comment: /main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please move your hibernate.cfg.xml to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF , It should work.

Comment: please clean the server and maven clean install.  It has to work